# BASH - commands string-like

Tags: bash, command, pwd

I am wondering if it is possible in BASH to use commands in this way:

lets take command `pwd`

Lets say I would like to have a variable `comm="pwd"`  and then use it somewhere in program, but when I use it, I get the real pwd command output. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do it — see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16133694/15168) by [hek2mgl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl).  In this simple case with a command and no arguments, it is straight-forward.  A command with simple space-less arguments is also OK.  If the command needs to preserve spaces in arguments, it is anything but straight-forward and there are probably better ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, you can just do:

```
comm='pwd'
# just execute
$comm
# fetch output into variable
output=$($comm)
```

Comment: -1 : this doesn't do anything : `comm='pwd'` but feeding the string 'pwd' to the comm variable

Comment: Where have you tested it? I'm using bash 4.2.25

Comment: @sputnick How can you say this?! indeed it works! Are you sure that you understood the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
var=$(pwd)
```

---

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: But this: var="$(ps -e -o "pid comm %mem user %cpu" --sort -%cpu | head -n 11)"
doesnt give the same output as this: ps -e -o "pid comm %mem user %cpu" --sort -%cpu | head -n 11

Comment: You need quotes on the variables like `echo "$var"`

Comment: "USE MORE QUOTES!" and "Double quote" _every_ expansion, as well as anything that could possibly contain a special character, e.g. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", "$(command)". Bash treats everything within 'single quotes' as literal. Learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Have you read the question? `Lets say I would like to have a variable comm="pwd" and then use it somewhere in program` .. Means not `use its output somewhere in program`

Comment: @hek2mgl: It's not clear after reading again OP question what is really asked here

Comment: I think it is clear. OP wants to store a command in a variable and execute it later. Can you please test my example using `bash example.sh` and tell me again that it `doesn't anything` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just surround the sub-command in backticks (the ` character):

```
comm=`pwd`
```

Comment: -1 for old style / not optimal to nest. Thanks to give best practices to new comers.

Comment: Thanks @sputnick, `$()` looks like a better solution